# Rime mais au début

Tags: phonétique, poésie, figure-de-style, son, phonème

Comment appelle-t-on la figure de style qui consiste à répéter un son semblable en début de mots ou en début de phrases ?

Cet usage est peu répandu en français où l’on préfère davantage les rîmes, mais en anglais il me semble que c’est le réflexe premier (Pensez à notre *J**o** le clod**o*** et à ***B**ily **B**oy*).

En fait, ce que je cherche, fonctionne selon le shéma suivant :

```
A_____
A_____
```

```
Argiens, la victoire est devant nous, enfin.
Arguons qu’il faille seulement tendre la main.
Armés, il n’y aura sur notre voie plus rien.
```

Je ne connais pas d’éxemple classique de cette figure de style, mais un exemple de mon cru donnerait quelque chose comme

### Non-buts

- Ce que je cherche n’est pas l’*anaphore*, car je ne cherche que la répétitions de phonèmes, de sons, et non de syntagmes, de mots.
- Ce n’est pas non plus la *prosonomastie* puisque les phonèmes répétés se trouvent en début de mots, ou de phrases.

### Épilogue

Comment donc s’appelle cette figure de style qui consiste à rappeler en début de mot, de proposition, ou de vers le même son ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas l'[assonance](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assonance) qui n'est pas obligatoirement en début de phrase. Ni l'allitération... t'as regardé [ici](https://philo-lettres.fr/old/litterature_francaise/tableau_recapitulatif_des_figure.htm) ?

Comment: Oui, @None j’ai vu des tableaux plus complets. Je sais que c’est une figure de répétition phonétique mais je ne parviens pas à mettre la main sur son nom.

Comment: En anglais, je crois qu'on l'appellerait "alliteration". Mais peut-être la définition française d'allitération est différente.

Comment: @PeterShor en effet, en français, l’[allitération](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allit%C3%A9ration) est la répétition de consonnes dans un texte sans aucun egard pour sa position dans la phrase ou le mot.

Comment: @None j’ai trouvé le [tautogramme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautogramme) qui s’en raproche déjà pas mal.

Comment: Accessoirement, pour citer quelques référence francophone similaire à "Billy Boy", je mentionnerais "Boule & Bill" ou "Chapi-Chapo". Je ne sais pas si Dupond et Dupont entrent dans la même catégorie...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les termes ne sont pas très courants (euphémisme...), mais cette figure de style peut être appelée :

> [Homéotéleute](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom%C3%A9ot%C3%A9leute) inverse
> Contre-homéotéleute
> Homéoarchton
> Homéoprotéron

Sources:

[*Jeux verbaux et créations verbales: Fonctionnement et illustrations*, Richard Arcand](https://books.google.fr/books?id=BqwhDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22Contre-hom%C3%A9ot%C3%A9leute%22&source=bl&ots=m9Tmth5kim&sig=ACfU3U1zUMoPz99y0WmWlUC8CkojskwOYg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSxfvTz_vxAhUByYUKHdCKDH0Q6AEwAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22Contre-hom%C3%A9ot%C3%A9leute%22&f=false)

> **L'homéotéleute inverse**
> Syn. **Le contre-homéotéleute**
> ...
> Les mêmes sons apparaîssent à l'initiale de plusieurs mots en contact ou à peu de distance.

[Blog le garde mots](http://blog.legardemots.fr/post/2005/10/26/414-chleuasme#c939180):

> L'**homéoarchton**, ou **homéoprotéron**, est une phrase dans laquelle plusieurs mots débutent par les mêmes lettres. Exemple : *Mon partenaire me paraît particulièrement paresseux*. Antonyme : *homéotéleute*.
>
> Il ne faut pas confondre avec l'*homéoarcton* : erreur de copiste qui consiste, dans un texte religieux, en l'omission de lettres ou de mots.